# Is boost::beast::static_string memcopyable/trivial type?

Tags: c++, type-traits, boost-beast

I am looking for a string implementation with fixed upper size that can be used in memcopy environment and that is trivially constructible and copyable.

I found boost beast static_string, but IDK if my [example](https://godbolt.org/z/mQKa9k) works by accident or no?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/beast/core/static_string.hpp>
boost::beast::static_string<16> s1("abc");

int main(){
    boost::beast::static_string<16> s2;
    std::copy_n((char*)&s1, sizeof(s2), (char*)&s2);
    s1.push_back('X');
    std::cout << "--" << std::endl;
    std::cout << s2 << std::endl;
    s2.push_back('Y');
    std::cout << s2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_trivial_v<decltype(s2)> << std::endl;
}
```

note: last line says type is not trivially copyable, but it could be just that Vinnie forgott to add a type trait.

P.S. I know this is a generally bad idea, what I am replacing is even worse, just a plain C array and modifying the allocation/copying to support std::string is much much more work.

Comment: how about `std::array<char,16>` ?

Comment: @idclev463035818 it is not user friendly, eg no push_back.

Comment: yes realized that this is a requirement, but still wrapping a array to turn its `size` into a `capacity` is probably still easier than getting `std::string` to work as you wish

Comment: @idclev463035818 I know std::string does not work, my question is about beast static_string

Comment: I know, I didnt attempt to answer your question

Comment: _but it could be just that Vinnie forgott to add a type trait_ — No, that's not the reason. `static_string` has a [user-provided copy constructor](https://github.com/boostorg/beast/blob/develop/include/boost/beast/core/impl/static_string.hpp#L85), therefore it cannot be a trivially-copyable type.

Comment: @DanielLangr thank you. Does type_traits have some other way for lib authors to signal their type can be memcopied and constructed without running a constructor?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Why some other way? Either a type is trivially-copyable or isn't. If the type trait can find out this automatically, there is no reason for any "signals from outside".

Comment: @DanielLangr my question is:
If library author wants to give answer to my questions(can I memcpy/ assume malloced class is properly constructed) does c++ give him any way to signal that with type traits?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Sorry, but still don't understand. Classes are trivially-copyable if they satisfy some [conditions posed by the C++ Standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.prop#1). They are not trivially-copyable because of type traits or some "signals". The type trait is only a way how to find out. In other words, you "signal" the trivial-copyability by the way how a class is designed.

Comment: @DanielLangr well that sucks... And about what I was asking: I was asking if the class author can say something about semantics of the class using c++.  Apparently not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically no, there are user defined copy constructors and operators (both call `assign`) which mean the class is not [trivially copyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable).

These appear to exist as an optimisation, if a `static_string` has a large size, but only stores a small string, `assign` only copies the used portion of the string, plus a null terminator.

C++ does not allow for [`std::is_trivially_copyable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable) to be specialized by programs, so I don't believe there is a way to get both at present.

`static_string` does just contain a `size_t` member and a `CharT[N+1]`, so if those two were default, it would be.

Comment: it is not allowed to specialize any trait of that family (`is_trivial`, `is_default_constructible`, etc), does that mean that one does not have to add specializations, because the compiler can detect those properties? When trying to find the answer I turned in circles, didnt find a trait that is not defined in terms of some other trait